# Presenting a view controller without changing the status bar color, like UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar, presentviewcontroller, uipresentationcontroller

When performing some network operations, I present a modal view controller (similar to MBProgressHUD but as a view controller) to prevent user interaction and indicate progress.

The view controller has `modalPresentationStyle = .Custom` and is animated using a transitioning delegate and custom presentation controller. Beyond animating the transitions they have no custom actions driving the presentation.

The problem I have is that whenever the view controller is presented, it turns the status bar color black.  I could override `preferredStatusBarStyle` to make it always return `.LightContent` but sometimes this view controller is presented over a view controller with `.Default` and I don't want to change it there either.  Basically, I want to have the same behavior as `UIAlertController`.

> [image: Screenshot showing presented view controller causing dark status bar content]

I have tried configuring the presentation controller to move the presented view controller out of the status bar space:

```
private class SEUIProgressControllerPresentationController: UIPresentationController {

    override func shouldPresentInFullscreen() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    private override func frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView() -> CGRect {
        return super.frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView().insetBy(dx: 40, dy: 100)
    }

    ...
}
```

These settings do move the top of the presented controller out of the status bar but the status bar is still affected.  Is there a property I am missing that would stop my view controller from updating the status bar style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update

It looks like this has been fixed in iOS 10.  The default behavior is to ignore the status bar rules from the presented view controller *unless* either the presented view controller has `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance == true` or you use one of several built-in presentation controllers that extend into the status bar space (not `.custom`).

Basically, the behavior for custom has changed to default opt-out rather than forced opt-in.

---

## For iOS 9.x and lower

After much digging, the internal logic for setting the application's status bar color looks like this:

```
var viewController = window.rootViewController!

while let presentedViewController = viewController.valueForKey("_presentedStatusBarViewController") as? UIViewController {
    viewController = presentedViewController
}

while let childViewController = viewController.childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle() {
    viewController = childViewController
}

let style = viewController.preferredStatusBarStyle()
```

The view controller's property `_presentedStatusBarViewController` is assigned during presentation based on the value of its presentation controller's private method `_shouldChangeStatusBarViewController()`.  The default implementation of this method is to return true, with `_UIAlertControllerPresentationController` and a handful of other presentation controllers returning false.

That means the most direct way to not change that status bar is simply to add this method to my presentation controller:

```
private class SEUIProgressControllerPresentationController: UIPresentationController {

    @objc func _shouldChangeStatusBarViewController() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this won't pass an App Store review.

Instead, what I am doing is recreating the logic that would be applied to the presenting view controller in my view controller:

```
public class SEUIProgressController: UIViewController {

    ...
    public override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {

        guard var targetViewController = presentingViewController else {
            return .LightContent
        }

        while let parentViewController = targetViewController.parentViewController {
            targetViewController = parentViewController
        }

        while let childViewController = targetViewController.childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle() {
            targetViewController = childViewController
        }

        return targetViewController.preferredStatusBarStyle()
    }

    public override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {

        guard var targetViewController = presentingViewController else {
            return false
        }

        while let parentViewController = targetViewController.parentViewController {
            targetViewController = parentViewController
        }

        while let childViewController = targetViewController.childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden() {
            targetViewController = childViewController
        }

        return targetViewController.prefersStatusBarHidden()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, is fixed since iOS 10 and is a weird issue if you are using a light status bar and you have to create a modal alert. You only have to set: controllerToPresent.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true, thanks.