# How to keep the control of status bar in the primary view controller

Tags: ios, statusbar

I have a view controller A and it shows the open page, then many other view controller will be pushed to A's controller, I want to let A keeps the control of status bar, but I try to set these in viewDidLoad it does not work. Anyone know how to ban the status bar controlling move to another view controller?

```
    [self setModalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance:YES];
    [self setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
```

Comment: Want to hide and show status bar or color change? I can't understand fully what you want?
[Check this link it may useful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35785737/3589771)

Comment: I want to implement hide show status bar in the code range of parent view controller.

Comment: Did you check above link? Did you have the key in `info.plist`?

Comment: I tried the answer but sadly it does not work.